# JasperReports 3.7 to 6.3 migration: How to replace PdfFont in font mapping code

Tags: java, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I am migrating some legacy JasperReports client code from Jasper 3.7 to Jasper 6.3. The code uses PdfFont class to do font mapping when exporting report to PDF.
The font mapping API in Jasper 6.3 seems to have changed a lot from 3.7 and I cannot find any examples of how to replace code to match new API.

The current code looks like this:

```
    String jasperTemplateFileName = ....;             
    JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport( jasperTemplateFileName, _jasperParams );

    File generatedPDFFile = ...;
    String outputFileName = generatedPDFFile.getAbsolutePath();

    JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, outputFileName);

    //Do font mapping. This is where I am having trouble
    HashMap fontMap = new HashMap();
    PdfFont boldPdfFont = new PdfFont(REPORT_FONTS_PATH + "arialbd.ttf", "Cp1252", true);
    FontKey fontKey = new FontKey("SansSerif",true,false);
    fontMap.put(fKey, boldPdfFont);

    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.FONT_MAP, fontMap);
    exporter.exportReport();
```

There is no PdfFont class in Jasper 6.3 and the replacement code is not obvious to me. Here is what I have so far:

```
Exporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jp));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputFileName));
                SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setPermissions(PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY | PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING);

//How to do font mapping here??

exporter.exportReport();
```

TIA for any guidance.

Comment: You should use [font extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions). Are you using styles or set font just in textFields?

Comment: Thanks. I would like to avoid XML files or new jar filesto package my font extensions. Is it possible to use the font extension mechanism entirely in Java code? If so, what would that look like? The legacy code is using the now removed FontMap mechanism that requires the PdfFont class that is no longer supported.

Comment: What is your exactly task? To set default font for all reports? As I can see from the first snippet you are using the reports templates. You can set the font for any textField or staticText. `Is it possible to use the font extension mechanism entirely in Java code?` - Yes.

Comment: The exact task is to set default normal, bold, italic and italicbold fonts for entire report conditional on the locale. Currently it is done entirely in Java code by setting the FontMap property on the Pdf Exporter where values are PdfFont objects. How can I do similar in jasper 6.3 entirely in Java code? Thanks for your kind help.